# Is there any alternative to jQuery .after() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I am trying to convert my jQuery script into javascript. I have a problem there..

I have a script that creates a node

```
var new_node = document.createElement("div");
      new_node.className="tooltip";
      new_node.innerHTML = html;
      alert(new_node.className);
```

When i do this

```
jQuery(link).after(new_node);
```

It works fine. But I want to do it javascript way. I have tried using `appendChild` function but it gives some strange results.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: 1) Can we see some more of the code? the generated HTML? the existing HTML? etc.. 2) Why are you switching from jQuery to JS? 3)Please work on improving your accept-rate. This is a community site, after all.

Comment: Just for the record, jQuery code **is** JavaScript code. I think what you mean is that you want to get away from using the library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're comparing jQuery's `after` with `appendChild`, but they do very different things. `after` puts the element *after* the reference element, `appendChild` puts it *inside* it.

You probably want [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-952280727) (with the reference node being `link`'s `nextSibling`).

So:

```
var link = /* ... get the `a` element from somewhere ... */;
var new_node = document.createElement("div");
new_node.className="tooltip";
new_node.innerHTML = html;
link.parentNode.insertBefore(new_node, link.nextSibling);
```

If `link` is the last thing in its parent, that's fine; `link.nextSibling` will be `null` and `insertBefore` accepts `null` as the reference node (it means "insert at the end").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a node instantiated as `link`, you could do what you want this way in plain Javascript:

```
link.parentNode.appendChild(new_node);
```

The `link` node would have to be the last node in its container. Otherwise you would have to find `link`'s nextSibling and use `insertBefore` to put `new_node` in its proper place.

Comment: This will work if "link" is already the last thing in its parent container, but if it's the first thing ...

Comment: Well, that'll certainly be after `link`. Possibly a **lot** after, and certainly not equivalent to jQuery's `after`.

Comment: @Pointy, T.J.: I noticed the problem probably at the same time you did and edited to fix. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @T.J.: If you get a reference to `link`'s nextSibling and do an `insertBefore` involving `new_node` then how does that not work?

Comment: Never mind. You've edited in a sentence at the end. I was just looking at the actual code. With the sentence you're fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
jQuery(link).append(new_node);
```

Comment: That is how you would append the node to the node reference by jQuery. To do it in 'pure' JS, it would required getting a reference to the DOMElement that needs to be appended to.